# Numpy Inheritance; add a method to Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance

Let's say we have a 2D array, `image`, eg. 20x20. I would like add a method, called 'imshow' to this object such that whenever I do `image.imshow(**kwargs)`), the method imshow will make a call of Matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of writing a class with an inheritance from numpy.ndarray, and adding a method 'imshow'.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer (thanks to [How can a class that inherits from a NumPy array change its own values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910013/how-can-a-class-that-inherits-from-a-numpy-array-change-its-own-values))!

```
class array(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, a):
        obj = np.asarray(a).view(cls)
        return obj

    def imshow(self, **kwargs):
        plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(self, **kwargs)
        plt.show()
```