# Numpy inheritance type

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to add a method to np.ndarray, so I have used inheritance as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765603/numpy-inheritance-add-a-method-to-numpy-array):

```
class array(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, a):
        obj = np.asarray(a).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return

    def some_kpi(self):
        pass
```

I expect that the type is still a np.ndarray, however `type(array)` returns `<class '__main__.array'>`. How can I change this to `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`? Any objections on this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `type(array)` shows the actual type, not all super-classes. If you do check the subclass: `issubclass(array, numpy.ndarray) == True` it should work?

Comment: True, but I would like to return the type numpy.ndarray. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A class is also a type. An instance of your new class 'array' is then also of the type 'array' which is a childclass or subtype from 'np.ndarray'.

Comment: @CyrielN My main point was that using `type` to try determine class structure/inheritance is an anti-pattern and should in general be avoided because it can be ambiguous. My assumption was that the questioner wasn't familiar enough with the (what I would say) appropriate solution.