# How do you add a method to a subclass of ndarray with __array_finalize__?

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance, subclass

I am looking at this [example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html) of subclassing numpy's `ndarray` class.

```
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        # add the new attribute to the created instance
        obj.info = info
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
```

How do I add a method to this subclass that can work on `input_array`, in a simple case: determine the maximum value in `input_array` (Let's ignore the fact that `ndarray` already possesses such a method). I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765603/numpy-inheritance-add-a-method-to-numpy-array). However, from my understanding, that only works for explicit constructor calls and misses the cases "view casting" and "new from template". A very naive attempt would be adding

```
    def SetMax(self):
        self.maximum = np.nanmax(self)
```

I think that this does not work since `self` is the pointer to the `RealisticInfoArray` instance and not the `ndarray` that is behind it. Iteration does not work either. However, changing one of the elements is possible.

```
    def ChangeValue(self):
        self[1]=0
```

I have thought about writing a static method

```
    @staticmethod
    def SetMax(a)
        return np.nanmax(a)
```

but I have no idea whether to call it in `__new__`, `__array_finalize__` or both in order to set `self.maximum`. I think in `__array_finalize__` would be enough but which argument do I provide? Both `self` and `obj` are pointers...